# How can I display my database-connection in MS Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: database-connection, dynamics-crm-2011

I can not find a way to display my database-connection in MS Dynamics CRM 2011. Is there a way to do this? I do have the rights of a sysadmin.

Comment: What do you mean by display? Do you know it and you want to put it somewhere? Or do you not know it, and want to find it?

Comment: I don't know it and I want to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way then is to open the Deployment Manager.

- Log onto your CRM machine as a deployment administrator (the user who installed CRM should be one of these).
- Start/Programs/Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and open Deployment Manager.
- Click Organizations, right click properties on your organization and it will show you the
  SQL Server.

[image]

[image]

(Images from [xrmadventures](http://xrmadventures.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/editing-ms-crm-2011-organizations-in-deployment-manager/))

Or you could look in the registry. Again log on the CRM machine, Start > Regedit, go to: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM

And have a look at the `configdb` key, will give you the full data source connection.

Comment: Hello James, thanks a lot for this great help! Now i know, how to get the informations I need.